# Mapping a list to 1s and 0s

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, data-science

I have two lists my_genre and list_of_genres. I want a function to check if `my_list[index]` is in `list_of_genres` and convert `list_of_genres[index2]` into a `1` if that is the case.

```
list_of_genres = ['Adventure', 'Animation', 'Children', 'Comedy', 'Fantasy', 'Drama', 'Romance', 'Action', 'Thriller', 'Sci-Fi', 'Crime', 'Horror', 'Mystery', 'IMAX', 'Documentary', 'War', 'Musical', 'Western', 'Film-Noir']


my_genre = ['Action', 'Crime', 'Drama', 'Thriller']
```

expected result:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
data type : np.array
```

Ultimately I want to apply the function that does this to a pandas column that contains the genres.

Answer (score 5):

Numpy isin is what you are looking for.

```py
results = np.isin(list_of_genres, my_genre).astype(int)
```

It's the same for pandas.

```py
list_of_genres = ['Adventure', 'Animation', 'Children', 'Comedy', 'Fantasy', 'Drama', 'Romance', 'Action', 'Thriller', 'Sci-Fi', 'Crime', 'Horror', 'Mystery', 'IMAX', 'Documentary', 'War', 'Musical', 'Western', 'Film-Noir']
my_genre = ['Action', 'Crime', 'Drama', 'Thriller']

df = pd.DataFrame({"genres" : list_of_genres})
df["my_genre"]  = df["genres"].isin(my_genre).astype(int)
print(df)
```

Comment: Note that while these approaches would provide the most widely accepted syntax, and they would outperform other approaches for large enough inputs, they are not as fast as some of the [other approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58393578/5218354), at least for the inputs you seems to have.

Answer (score 1):

A `map()` based solution producing a `list`:

```
ll = list(map(int, map(my_genre.__contains__, list_of_genres)))
print(ll)
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

---

For the result to be `numpy.ndarray()` you could use `np.fromiter()`:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.fromiter(map(my_genre.__contains__, list_of_genres), dtype=int)
print(arr)
# [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

---

For larger inputs, `np.in()` should be the fastest. For inputs of this size, the `map()` approach is ~6 times faster than `np.isin()`, ~65 times faster than the `pandas` solution, and ~40% faster than a comprehension.

```
%timeit np.isin(list_of_genres, my_genre).astype(int)                                                                                        
# 15.8 µs ± 385 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit np.fromiter(map(my_genre.__contains__, list_of_genres), dtype=int)                                                                   
# 2.55 µs ± 27.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit np.fromiter((my_genre.__contains__(x) for x in list_of_genres), dtype=int)                                                           
# 4.14 µs ± 19.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit df["genres"].isin(my_genre).astype(int)                                                                                              
# 167 µs ± 2.26 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

---

This can be further speed up by converting `my_genre` to a `set` prior to the application of the `in`/`.__contains__` operator:

```
%timeit np.fromiter(map(set(my_genre).__contains__, list_of_genres), dtype=int)                                                              
# 1.9 µs ± 7.17 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: Note that for a one-time execution, even 65 times basically instantaneous, is still basically instantaneous.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, although your question is poorly formulated.

```
list_of_genres = ['Adventure', 'Animation', 'Children', 'Comedy', 'Fantasy', 'Drama', 'Romance', 'Action', 'Thriller', 'Sci-Fi', 'Crime', 'Horror', 'Mystery', 'IMAX', 'Documentary', 'War', 'Musical', 'Western', 'Film-Noir']
my_genre = ['Action', 'Crime', 'Drama', 'Thriller']

idx = [1 if g in my_genre else 0 for g in list_of_genres]
```

Output:

```
Out[13]: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

If you want a numpy array, then simply convert it into one with `numpy.asarray()`. And to apply it to a dataframe, simply change the elements `my_genre` and `list_of_genres` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
>>> list_of_genres = ['Adventure', 'Animation', 'Children', 'Comedy', 'Fantasy', 'Drama', 'Romance', 'Action', 'Thriller', 'Sci-Fi', 'Crime', 'Horror', 'Mystery', 'IMAX', 'Documentary', 'War', 'Musical', 'Western', 'Film-Noir']


>>> my_genre = ['Action', 'Crime', 'Drama', 'Thriller']
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> [1 if el in my_genre else 0 for el in list_of_genres]

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `pandas` as your tags suggest you can do

```py
import pandas as pd
list_of_genres = ['Adventure', 'Animation', 'Children', 'Comedy',
                  'Fantasy', 'Drama', 'Romance', 'Action', 'Thriller',
                  'Sci-Fi', 'Crime', 'Horror', 'Mystery', 'IMAX',
                  'Documentary', 'War', 'Musical', 'Western', 'Film-Noir']

my_genre = ['Action', 'Crime', 'Drama', 'Thriller']

df = pd.DataFrame({"genre": list_of_genres})

df["genre"].apply(lambda x: x in my_genre).astype(int)

# or even faster

df["genre"].isin(my_genre).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it as a nice little one liner:

```
list_of_genres = ['Adventure', 'Animation', 'Children', 'Comedy', 'Fantasy', 'Drama', 'Romance', 'Action', 'Thriller', 'Sci-Fi', 'Crime', 'Horror', 'Mystery', 'IMAX', 'Documentary', 'War', 'Musical', 'Western', 'Film-Noir']
my_genre = ['Action', 'Crime', 'Drama', 'Thriller']

result = np.array([int(my_genre.__contains__(n)) for n in list_of_genres])
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension as 1 line solution

```
bool_list = [1 if item in my_genre else 0 for item in list_of_genres]
```

If you sort of new to this and don't quite understand list comprehension you can split it in a for loop

```
bool_list =[]
for item in list_of_genres:
    if(item in my_genre):
        bool_list.append(1)
    else:
        bool_list.append(0)
```